# Can't register EC2 instance in ELB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb

I'm trying to set up an AWS environment for the first time and have so far got a DNS entry pointing to a Classic ELB. I also have an EC2 instance running but I don't seem to be able to add the EC2 instance to the ELB in the UI. The documentation says that I can do this in the "Instances" tab in Load balancer screen but I don't have the tab at all. All I can see is Description | Listeners | Monitoring | Tags.

Does anyone have any ideas why the "Instances" tab night be missing from the UI?

Comment: It sounds like you created an Application Load Balancer (ELB/2), not a Classic balancer (ELB/1).

Comment: Post the screenshot, I do agree with @Michael-sqlbot comment, you might be using ALB instead of Classic ELB. In case of ALB you will add "instances" to target groups, not directly to ALB.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot you're spot on. I'd mistakenly created an application load balancer and not a Classic one. Thanks for the help, if you want to create an answer for it I'll obviously accept.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are now two different types of Elastic Load Balancer.

ELB/1.0, the original, is now called a "Classic" balancer.

ELB/2.0, the new version, is an "Application Load Balancer" (or "ALB").

They each have [different features and capabilities](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/userguide/what-is-load-balancing.html).

One notable difference is that ALB doesn't simply route traffic *to instances*, it routes traffic *to targets on instances*, so (for example) you could pool multiple services on the same instance (e.g. port 8080, 8081, 8082) even though those requests all came into the balancer on port 80.  And these targets are configured in virtual objects called target groups.  So there are a couple of new abstraction layers, and this part of the [provisioning workflow](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/userguide/load-balancer-getting-started.html) is much different.  It's also provisioned using a different set of APIs.

Since the new Application Load Balancer is the default selection in the console wizard, it's easy to click past it, not realizing that you've selected something other than the classic ELB you might have been expecting, and that sounds like what occurred in this case.

Answer (score 0):

It might be possible that you have selected Application Load Balancer instead of selecting Classic Load Balancer.
If that is the case, then you need to add your instance in Target Group as Instances tab is not available in the Application Load Balancer.

I hope above may resolve your case.